# Remap CAPS_LOCK key for both virtual consoles and desktop environment in one easy step

Tags: keyboard-layout

I want my CAPS_LOCK key to be another CTRL key in both virtual consoles and my desktop environment. I know there are dozens of ways to accomplish this. However, a while back I came across an elegant way to make this change permanent and to accomplish it in one step (i.e., the change made affects both console and DE).

Now I am installing a new system and I cannot locate that method. Every method I find via a Google search is either for X only or requires making separate changes for consoles and X.

I'm hoping someone here can help me locate the elegant method I ran across previously and have now lost.